# SQL Server - Multiple Transaction ID's - If contains - Only select Latest

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Apologies for the unclear title.

I am attempting to create a time verification report in SQL but have hit a wall.

The issue I am facing is that is that sometimes changes are made by support staff after an employee has submitted their time and the only way to differentiate these is by the Transaction ID. For example, if John Doe submitted his time card his Transaction ID in the table would be 1234 but if a change was made to that entry the Transaction ID in the table would be 1234-00 then 1234-01 then 1234-02 and so on for each change. What I want to do is alter my SQL query so that if the Transaction ID contains a - it only selects the latest entry.

See Sample Code Below:

```
SELECT
    jb_id AS JobID,
    MAX(jb_nme) AS JobName,
    MAX(emplye_nme_frst) + ' ' + MAX(emplye_nme_lst) AS FullName,
    jchstry_dte_effctve AS EffectiveDate,
    jchstry_hrs,
    pytype_id PayType,
    jbcstctgry_id,
    jbcstctgry_dscrptn,
    jchstry_srce_trnsctn_id
FROM jb
JOIN jbbllngitm
    ON jbbllngitm.jb_rn = jb.jb_rn
JOIN jbcstcde
    ON jbcstcde.jb_rn = jb.jb_rn
JOIN jchstry
    ON jbcstcde.jbcstcde_rn = jchstry.jbcstcde_rn
JOIN pytype
    ON pytype.pytype_rn = jchstry.pytype_rn
JOIN jbcstctgry
    ON jbcstctgry.jbcstctgry_rn = jchstry.jbcstctgry_rn
JOIN emplye
    ON jchstry_rfrnce_rn = emplye.emplye_rn
WHERE jb_id = '1234'
AND jchstry_dte_effctve BETWEEN 'XXXX-04-01' AND 'XXXX-04-04'
GROUP BY jbcstcde_nme,
         jb.jb_rn,
         jchstry.jchstry_dte_effctve,
         jb.jb_id,
         pytype.pytype_id,
         jbcstctgry.jbcstctgry_id,
         jbcstctgry.jbcstctgry_dscrptn,
         jchstry.jchstry_hrs,
         jchstry.jchstry_srce_trnsctn_id
```

Sample DataSet

```
JobID  JobName  FullName  EffectiveDate  Hours  PayType Source  Transaction ID
1234    XXXX    John Doe    4/1/XXXX     0.25   Straight Time     5678
1234    XXXX    John Doe    4/1/XXXX     8      Straight Time     5678-01
1234    XXXX    John Doe    4/4/XXXX     8      Straight Time     4567
```

For example in the table above since there are two transaction ID's for 5678 I only want to select the transaction ID that contains the -01. If the results had transaction ID 5678-01, 5678-02, and 5678-03 I would only want the query to return that line with 5678-03.

Please let me know if anything is unclear. This was harder to explain than I had anticipated.

Comment: Put the '01' in a new column and query the max for that column and group by transaction id?

Comment: But there are entries that will  not have any -01,-02 values at all. The 4567 Transaction ID is correct and did not have any changes made.

Comment: Is there a date timestamp column that records the timestamp after each change? and which version of SQL-Server are you using ?

Comment: @AdrianWarness That wont be an issue then.  It will be a NULL in the column and will only return the one row when you look for the max.

Comment: There is a jchstry_id column as well as jchstry_pstd_tme. SQL Server 2008

Comment: Which represents what? Can you explain those columns

Comment: The id column is the unique ID and the pstd_tme column is when the change was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys are too smart and I had trouble following your answers. I was able to figure it out today. Here is what I ended up with. Thanks again to all for your help.

```
With TimeVerifcation as (
select 
jb_id as JobID,
max(jb_nme) as JobName,
emplye_id as EmployeeID,
max(emplye_nme_frst) + ' ' + max(emplye_nme_lst) as FullName, 
jbbllngitm_dscrptn as JobBillingItem,
jchstry_dte_effctve as EffectiveDate,
jchstry_hrs as Hours,
max(pytype_id) PayType,
jbcstctgry_id as CostCategoryID,
jbcstctgry_dscrptn as CostCategoryDescription,
row_number() over (partition by jbbllngitm_dscrptn,jchstry_dte_effctve,emplye_id,pytype_id  order by jchstry_pstd_dte + ' ' + jchstry_pstd_tme desc) as RN
from jb
join jbcstcde on jbcstcde.jb_rn = jb.jb_rn
join jchstry on jbcstcde.jbcstcde_rn = jchstry.jbcstcde_rn
join pytype on pytype.pytype_rn = jchstry.pytype_rn
join jbcstctgry on jbcstctgry.jbcstctgry_rn = jchstry.jbcstctgry_rn
join emplye on jchstry_rfrnce_rn = emplye.emplye_rn
join jbbllngitm on jbbllngitm.jbbllngitm_rn = jchstry.jbbllngitm_rn
where jb_id = '72681-00'
and emplye_nme_lst = 'Cortez'
and jchstry_dte_effctve between '2016-04-01' and '2016-04-04'
group by jchstry.jchstry_dte_effctve,jb.jb_id,jbcstctgry.jbcstctgry_id,jbcstctgry.jbcstctgry_dscrptn,jchstry.jchstry_hrs,jbbllngitm.jbbllngitm_dscrptn,emplye.emplye_id,pytype.pytype_id,jchstry.jchstry_pstd_dte,jchstry.jchstry_pstd_tme
)
Select *
from TimeVerifcation
where RN=1
order by EffectiveDate
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no unique ID column, and no timestamp of last entry, you can inner join to itself. Here are the results you provided. The inner join is to the max transactionID. The key here is to include enough columns on the join to be unique while ignoring columns that would be edited. Not elegant but neither is not having a timestamp or unique ID column
drop table #temp

```
SELECT
1234 as JobID,'XXXX' as JobName,'John Doe' as FullName,'4/1/2016' as EffectiveDate,0.25 as Hours,'Straight' as PayType,'Time' as Source,'5678' as TransactionID
INTO #temp
UNION ALL
SELECT
1234,'XXXX','John Doe','4/1/2016',8,'Straight','Time','5678-01'
UNION ALL 
SELECT
1234,'XXXX','John Doe','4/4/2016',8,'Straight','Time','4567'

SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT
    t.JobID, t.JobName, t.FullName, t.EffectiveDate, t.Hours, t.PayType, t.Source, t.TransactionID
FROM
    #temp t
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT JobID, JobName, FullName, EffectiveDate, PayType, Source, MAX(TransactionID) TransactionID
    FROM #temp
    GROUP BY JobID, JobName, FullName, EffectiveDate, PayType, Source) t2 on
    t2.JobID = t.JobID and 
    t2.JobName = t.JobName and 
    t2.FullName = t.FullName and 
    t2.EffectiveDate = t.EffectiveDate and
    t2.PayType = t.PayType and
    t2.Source = t.Source and
    t2.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
```

Comment: There is a jchstry_id column as well as  jchstry_pstd_tme

Answer (score 1):

I test it in SSMS as per your request. It works very well.
PS: I use temp table #test as the table with the given structure and data. Please do the modification appropriately. :)

```
-- Create table structure
    create table #test(
        JobID int,
        JobName varchar(10),
        FullName varchar(50),
        EffectiveDate date,
        Hours money,
        PayType varchar(10),
        Source varchar(10),
        TransactionID varchar(10)
    )

 --Insert Data into the temp table       
        insert #test
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/1/1990',     0.25,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/1/1990',     8,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678-01'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/4/1990',     8,   'Straight', 'Time',     '4567'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/1/1990',     9,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678-02'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/6/1990',     123,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678-03'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/12/1990',     23,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678-04'


        insert #test
        select 2345,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/12/1990',     23,   'Straight', 'Time',     '2342'
        union all
        select 2345,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/12/1990',     23,   'Straight', 'Time',     '2342-01'

 --Below is the solution for this question.   

        select jobid,jobname,fullname,effectivedate,hours,paytype,source,transactionid
                 from 
                 (
                    select *,max(a.orderbyid_in)over(partition by a.partitionid) as orderbyid_out
                    from 
                    (
                        select *,
                            (case when charindex('-',TransactionID) <> 0 then left(TransactionID,charindex('-',TransactionID)-1)
                                  else TransactionID
                             end) as partitionid, 
                            (case when charindex('-',TransactionID) <> 0 then right(TransactionID,charindex('-',reverse(TransactionID))-1)
                                  else '00'
                             end) as orderbyid_in 
                        from #test

                    ) as a


                ) as b
                where (transactionid = partitionid and orderbyid_out = '00')
                      or
                      (transactionid = partitionid +'-'+orderbyid_out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we can solve this ( Thanks to @Dance-Henry for some of the test data that I modified )

```
   create table #test
    (
        JobID int,
        JobName varchar(10),
        FullName varchar(50),
        EffectiveDate date,
        Hours money,
        PayType varchar(10),
        Source varchar(10),
        TransactionID varchar(10),
        jchstry_id int,
        jchstry_pstd_tme datetime
    )

    delete #test

 --Insert Data into the temp table       
        insert #test
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/1/2016',     0.25,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678' , 1, '4/1/2016 01:00:00'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/1/2016',     8,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678-01' , 2, '4/1/2016 02:00:00'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/4/2016',     8,   'Straight', 'Time',     '4567'    , 1 , '4/4/2016 03:00:00'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/1/2016',     9,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678-02' ,  3 , '4/1/2016 03:00:00'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/6/2016',     123,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678-03' , 4, '4/6/2016 04:00:00'
        union all
        select 1234,    'XXXX',    'John Doe',    '4/12/2016',     23,   'Straight', 'Time',     '5678-04'  , 5, '4/12/2016 05:00:00'
        union all
        select 2345,    'XXXX',    'Mike Smith',    '4/12/2016',     23,   'Straight', 'Time',     '2342'    , 1 , '4/12/2016 03:00:00'
        union all
        select 2345,    'XXXX',    'Mike Smith',    '4/12/2016',     23,   'Straight', 'Time',     '2342-01'  , 2 , '4/12/2016 04:00:00'
```

**Query:**

```
Select * From
(

 select *,  
 Left(TransactionID+'-', CHARINDEX('-',TransactionID+'-') ) Lft, 
 Rank() Over ( Partition by FullName, Left(TransactionID+'-', CHARINDEX('-',TransactionID+'-') ) Order By jchstry_id desc , jchstry_pstd_tme desc) as Rnk
 from #test 

 ) A Where Rnk =1
```

**Logic:** It ranks the rows by FullName,Transaction_ID (Upto the dash) and the oldest record comes at rank=1 because we are ordering by jchstry_id desc , jchstry_pstd_tme desc. After that we select only those those records that have Rnk=1.